# problem occurred evaluating root project 'android A problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter

hi Guys i am totally new in coding and i have no idea about that

however i have purchased stackfood app recently and i found out that all the Android apps require some changes in android studio

i have followed thier documentations exactly and everything seems fine with me however there is a problem when i build apk

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mogha\OneDrive\Desktop\YumYum\codecanyon-8CoFNnIb-stackfood-multi-restaurant-food-delivery-app-with-laravel-admin-and-restaurant-panel-v10\User app and web\android\build.gradle' line: 34

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl.
      > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

        If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value i
n the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           38.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

and this is flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2715], locale en-GB)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: if you are using latest gradle version then from Manifest file you have to remove  package attribute and inside app/buil.gradle file inside android tag you have to add namespace with you package name of app.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now I am getting another error.            * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':connectivity'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

Comment: you can go to that connectivity module and find for android folder and inside app.build.gradle file and add namespace which is defined as package in manifest file and remove package attribute from manifest as well for connectivity module